# How often should rules be reminded?

Tags: rules

Usually all of us set up some rules (house rules, behavior rules, safety rules, ...) that we desire that our children follow.

When and how often should we remind the rules?

More specifically I saw a video on you-tube where they conducted a social experiment where they tried to get kids away from the parents. The rule here would be "Do not talk with strangers"

Comment: Not related to your question, but to your example: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/is-it-harmful-to-a-childs-social-development-to-tell-them-dont-talk-to-strang

Comment: Has it not been amply demonstrated by now that "don't talk to stragers" is about as silly as rules get, and that children are much more likely to be harmed by people they know?

Comment: @fkraiem My example probably wasn't the best. Eric Renouf already pointed a really good link in how to deal with this specific example. But please be aware that my question is `When and how often should we remind the rules?`

Answer (score 2):

As often as necessary.  Depending on the child and the rule, once may be enough.  Other times it may take many, many constant reminders.  There is no magic one-size-fits-all number.

For example, if you know or suspect your child will have problems remembering not to talk to strangers, remind them when you are about to go somewhere where they might have to deal with strangers.  If you can ask the child what to do when they encounter a stranger and they can remember on their own, they may not need to be reminded any more.  Also, reminding them when they are likely to need that information will help them to better remember it.

Age is only a small factor in how much you may need to remind a child.  Small children typically need more repetition to remember some things but this isn't always the case.  Some small kids get it on the first or second try.  Some older kids need to be reminded a lot before they remember.  And any kid is subject to forgetting something when they are caught up in the moment.

Comment: One of my friends has to have a brief discussion with her (five-ish) son every time they go to the park about how Mommy wants him to stay with her, and that if he goes running off then he has to ride in the stroller. She doesn't bring it up out of context, but she does have to remind him /every/ time they go to the park or he'll book it. So I would say remind them when the rule is relevant, and as often as necessary within that circumstance, as @Becuzz stated.

Answer (score 0):

You should have consequences if the rules are not followed.  Post the rules in an "If..Then.." format, and when they break them, take them to the list and have a pre-defined consequence.  You have to remind them of the rules, likely hourly, then daily until they learn to follow your expectations!

Good Luck!